# Web client was not able to connect to the MQTT web socket

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have created a MQTT broker, and I have configured a web socket.
This is my configuration file. (I don't use SSL)

```
#mqtt
listener 1883
protocol mqtt

#Websockets
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

I running my MQTT broker (with this command `$ mosquitto -c /path/to/mosquitto.conf`) and this is the log file.

```
1569230648: mosquitto version 1.4.15 (build date Tue, 18 Jun 2019 11:42:22 -0300) starting
1569230648: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1569230648: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1569230648: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1569230648: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
```

In my web site I have this code.

```
<!-- Script to import MQTT -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paho-mqtt/1.0.1/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>


<!-- Script to connect to MQTT broker and retrieve current values -->
<script>
var websocket =  "195.**.***.**"; 
    var port =  9001; 

    client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(websocket, port, "web_connection" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));    

    // set callback handlers
    client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;


    var options = {
        onSuccess: onConnect,
        onFailure: doFail
    }

    // connect the client

    client.connect(options);
    .....
```

But when I try to connect with my web site, Chrome get this error:

```
mqttws31.js:977 WebSocket connection to 'ws://195.**.***.**:9001/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I open in my router 9001 port. Why can't the client web connect?

Thanks

Comment: Have you remembered to open port 9001 in the firewall (and/or enabled the required port forwarding)

Comment: Thanks for the support. I opened the door in the router firewall. To create the web socket, do I have to do something besides modify the mosquito configuration file?

Comment: No, timeout errors imply a firewall dropping packets or you've got the IP address wrong

Comment: Firewall in my Ubuntu is disable. The IP address is correct. Do Maybe I have to use SSL? Or Do I have to create a domain name?

Comment: No, as I said already, timeout is either something dropping packets (a firewall somewhere on the path) or the wrong IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the support. All is ok. I'm not an expert in this field ... is it possible that we need to create a web socket? or just change the configuration file   `listener 9001
protocol websockets`  and the web socket is created?

Comment: Thanks, the error is the IP. Infact I use IP Public but in my network I must to use IP Private.

Comment: This implies you didn't set up port forwarding as I originally suggested (or your router doesn't support hair pin routing)

Comment: Yes, thanks so much